# AutofacContrib.NSubstitute: TypeLoadException after upgrading to AutoFac6 and v6.2.2

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofac, nsubstitute

I get this in all my tests now whenever calling new `AutoSubstitute();` or `AutoSubstitute.Configure().Build();`

System.TypeLoadException : Method 'RegistrationsFor' in type 'AutofacContrib.NSubstitute.NSubstituteRegistrationHandler' from assembly 'AutofacContrib.NSubstitute, Version=4.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
at AutofacContrib.NSubstitute.AutoSubstituteBuilder.InternalBuild()
at AutofacContrib.NSubstitute.AutoSubstituteBuilder.Build()

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you take a major upgrade (when the version of a library increments by a whole number - 5.0.0 to 6.0.0 sort of increment) it's good to check the release notes. A whole number increment means there are breaking changes.

[The Autofac release notes for v6.0.0](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/releases/tag/v6.0.0) specifically note:

> **Breaking Changes:**
>
> ...
>
> `IRegistrationSource` implementations need to update the `RegistrationsFor` method signature.

I'd wager the AutofacContrib.NSubstitute library has not, itself, taken the upgrade, but also hasn't specified that it doesn't work with Autofac v6.

If I were you, I'd file an issue with the AutofacContrib.NSubstitute library to get that fixed.